# Is it possible to connect Mininet and OpenDayLight controller in two different physical machine?

Tags: simulation, sdn, mininet, opendaylight, virtual-network

I've been working in a simple project to learn the basics for SDN virtual testbed with Mininet and Opendaylight controller. I'm a newbie in SDN domain. It would be helpful for me if someone highlight some source to learn Mininet and remote controller testbed implementation. Currently, I deployed Mininet and Opendaylight in two different physical machines, which are connected with ethernet cable. The issue is the reachability test (`Pingall`) failed in mininet machine. The native ping test between two physical machine is reachable; however, the reachability between hosts in mininet is failed.

Is it the problem of physical connection?

OR

Are there any configuration needed to connect the mininet deployed machine and Opendaylight deployed machine?

Comment: Hi @RazielNaing , did you find a solution to your problem of the pinging not working? I am facing a similar issue. Thank you!

Comment: Hello @DhruvRauthan, I didn't find the solution. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure your controller is up and running
2. write down the IP address of your controller
3. Instruct mininet to use remote controller `sudo mn --controller=remote,ip=[controller IP],port=[controller listening port]`

The [controller IP] is the IP address of your controller and the [controller listening port] would be most probably 6633 or 6653, both should work.